# AngularJS - ngRepeat. Need to keep focus on the same element event after ng-repeat re rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of three inputs, each of them can be deleted by the user by pressing a red cross placed at the left side of them. When the user delete one input, the next one is focused and the selected checkbox is deleted. Until there so far so good.
After deleting the element the ng-repeat loop iterates over the updated model and I lose the element focus. Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks so much,

Guillermo

PD: Including the directive code just in case.

```
directive('checkEmptyInput', function ($timeout,$q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if(!ngModel) return; //do nothing if no ng-model

            var idx = scope.$index,
                array = [],
                fieldIsValid = false;



            element.on('keyup', function () {


                switch (attrs.checkEmptyInput) {
                    case "method":
                        array = scope.album.tracks;

                        fieldIsValid = scope.ngAlbumForm.track.$valid;
                    break;
                }

                if(array[idx].name && array[idx].name != "" && fieldIsValid) {
                    array[idx].active = true;
                } else {
                    array[idx].active = false;


                    if(scope.elementHasId(array[idx])){
                        scope.deleteKeyFromCombinationsCodes(array[idx].id);
                    }
                };

                if (array[idx].name == "") {

                    //Previous to delete focus the next element
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var nextElem = element.parent().next().find('input')[0];

                        if(nextElem !== undefined) {

                            if(!scope.$last) {

                                //Delete the element
                                console.log("Deleting from inside the directive...");
                                nextElem.focus();                                   
                                scope.$emit("deleteArrayElement", [idx]);

                            }

                        }

                    });

                }

            });

        }
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
                    <div ng-repeat="track in album.tracks">
                        <input check-empty-input="track" type="text" ng-change="addInputText($index,$last,track.name,album.tracks;" ng-minlength="3" class="album_tracks" ng-model="track.name" ng-unique="track"/><button type="button"/>
                        <i class="remove-icon"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BRN9csBcxHp5QU96NKq9?p=info

Comment: looks like you misunderstood angular directives :
"element.on('keyup', " should be inside directive template as ngkeyup (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeyup) and every interaction as separate function. Can you provide jsfiddle so we can see html also?

Comment: Daniel: Thanks so much, the code works as expected, but the undesired behavior is that I lose the focus on the element once the ng-repeat renders again the updated model after deleting the selected option. I've added the html snippet

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see with the plunk.  `ng-repeat` re-uses elements and you pick the index during initial linking.  If you set `idx` inside your `keyup` handler it works.  [(PLNKR)](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWmcOpYnXoCuI1mMCfLh?p=preview)

```
element.on('keyup', function () {
    idx = scope.$index;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked great. Although in my original scenario Im still having issues, due that document.activeElement is the desired element, but it doesn´t have the cursor in its place, this gives me a clue on whats going wrong.

Comment: For the sake of completness, my issue was raised due that AngularJS 1.0.8 has a bug when focusing elements, after working with them. In the same plunker if you use angular 1.0.8, it wont work. The issue seems to be fixed in 1.2.0 RC3. Thanks so much again!